# PDO query appears to be returning DESC order. Ignoring ASC hardcode

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im new to PDO so maybe some subtle nuance that I am not aware of. But I have a query that is supposed to list the drivers by date ASC. The code works the right way, ASC when I test in workbench, so I know the test table data is solid; but when I run the below code in PDO, it does not show any error and returns the record but im seeing the results for DESC order by not ASC like expected. Here's the code:

```
$selectsql = "SELECT driverid, busid, firstname
FROM drivers 
WHERE active= 1 
AND day= 1
ORDER BY ? ASC
LIMIT ? ";

$results = $pdo->prepare($selectsql);
$results->execute([$list_date,$count]);

$row = $results->fetchAll();
```

I get no error and data is returned. Just not in order expected. 
I did check and the 2 variables $list_date and $count are set properly.

Does anyone see what it possibly could be?

**UPDATE**

Im finding that it is sorting by the primary index driversid. I have no idea why.

Comment: `mysqli_error()` doesn't mix with PDO.

Comment: `PARAM_STR` is the wrong type for integers.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks, hmm query still worked and changing it did not help. And for the mysqli, I can just remove it and it will still kick errors on its own right. I set it to do so during DSN

Comment: Note with PDO you don't really need `bindParam()`, instead just do `$results->execute([$list_date, $count]);`. Also, do you have `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to false?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes I do. I followed the tutorial at: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Im finding that it is sorting by the index driversid. I have no idea why

Comment: What is this `ORDER BY ? ASC` for? And what does your parameter `$list_date` include?

Comment: I use console_log() to verify that its holding the string I want, which is the column name "day_date". I want to sort the drivers by that date field. So the oldest date is on top after sorting ASC. But the NEWEST date shows; come to find its sorting by the primary key driversid, for some reason. Im telling it to sort by day_date. Its ignoring it. When I run the same code in workbench, it works perfectly and orders by ASC of that field. So something about PDO and using variables is making it omit the ASC directive, it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot use a field name as parameter for a prepared statement. You can change your code to something like this:

```php
$selectsql = "SELECT driverid, busid, firstname
    FROM drivers 
    WHERE active= 1 
    AND day= 1
    ORDER BY " . $list_date . " ASC
    LIMIT ? ";

$results = $pdo->prepare($selectsql);
$results->execute([$count]);

$row = $results->fetchAll();
```

Comment: In case of insecure data in `$list_date` (user input), be aware of SQL injection.

Comment: thats! works perfectly now. Weird how PDO does not kick an error and just sorts arbitrarily like that. Beginners nightmare kinda. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting by a constant expression, not a column, so the sort order will basically be arbitrary (not even random).

If you want to inject code into a SQL statement (such as a column name) you need to use good old string manipulation functions. Prepared statements are specifically designed to *avoid* that:

```
$selectsql = "SELECT driverid, busid, firstname
    FROM drivers 
    WHERE active= 1 
    AND day= 1
    ORDER BY $list_date ASC
    LIMIT ? ";
$results = $pdo->prepare($selectsql);
$results->execute([$count]);
$row = $results->fetchAll();
```

Make sure that `$list_date` is valid SQL you have full control on and not external input.

Comment: This answer does work as its basically the same as @henrik below, but he posted first and his explanation is clearer to me, simply "you cannot use a field name as a parameter." thanks anyway. He beat you by 5 minutes :-)

Comment: Don't worry, this is not a race. I just wanted to *explain* why. Thank you for accepting an answer, not everybody does!